# CSS- Expanding Child Element But Keeping Dimensions of Parent Intact. To Create a Drop Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I want to create a drop down menu (alternate to Browswer's `<select>` tag).

So Here I've created a `<div>` in another `<div>` to stimulate the `<select>`

But When I expand the `dropdown <div>` automatically parent `<div>` also expands making structure of page very dirty.

I mean, Here is **output of my actual code**:
[image: Original]

**When I click on Expand** The Result Is:
[image]

But **I want output, When I click on Expand** like:
[image]

Here is My Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drop Down Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .ddown{
        width:250px;
        min-height: 25px;
        background: #aaa;
        border: 2px solid #777;
        color: #444;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .ddown a{
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        text-align: left;
        color: #666;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #ddd;
        border: 1px solid #999;
    }
    .ddownHead{
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
    .ddownItem{
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
    .ddownItem:hover{
        background: #33a;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .ddown_busy{
        background: #77a !important;
        border: 1px solid #558 !important;
        color: #fff !important;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_expand_ddown(x){
        if($(x).closest("div").find("a").eq(0).hasClass("ddown_busy")){
            $(x).closest("div").find("a").eq(0).removeClass("ddown_busy");
        $(x).closest("div").find("div").each(function(){
            $(this).find("a").each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("ddownItem");
            });
        });
        }
        else
        {
        $(x).closest("div").find("a").eq(0).addClass("ddown_busy");
        $(x).closest("div").find("div").each(function(){
            $(this).find("a").each(function(){
                $(this).addClass("ddownItem");
            });
        });
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%;height:25px;background:#aa0;border:2px solid #770;">
    <div class="ddown">
    <a class="ddownHead" href="#!" Onclick="toggle_expand_ddown(this);">Click to Expand</a>
    <div>
        <a href="#!">Item 1</a>
        <a href="#!">Item 1</a>
        <a href="#!">Item 1</a>
        <a href="#!">Item 1</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    This is Another Child in same Parent
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've Also Created Fiddle

## [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/Smith_jones_1111/FuhgN/).

I think It is Because of `CSS` only. But However Any suggestions are welcome.Hope You'll Help me Soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having problem with opening and closing `<div>` tags

I tried to add a `<div>` tag to the another child and this `**css**`:

```
.div2{
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FuhgN/1/)**

or this without using position absolute by adding this `css` to your main div:

```
overflow: visible;
vertical-align: top;
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/FuhgN/2/)**

or by adding `float:left` to the `.ddown` css

**[FIDDLE DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/FuhgN/3/)**

PS: I think option 1 is a better practice, you'll just have to put every child in a `<div>` tag

Comment: Nice Catch! But Rather Adding Another `div` with `absolute` positioning; can it be fixed without it, Coz There isn't only that one child in my real example, I've added only 1 in fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. But It Only Works in Chrome, and Fails Firefox and others.

Comment: add float: left to the .ddown.. I've updated my answer check DEMO 3